# expected google.protobuf.Duration got str

Tags: python, google-cloud-monitoring, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to create an alert with Cloud Functions. I have the following test alert json directly inserted into my code:

```
alert_policy = {"conditions":[{"condition_absent":{"duration":900s,"filter":"metric.label.state=\"blocked\" AND metric.type=\"agent.googleapis.com/processes/count_by_state\"  AND resource.type=\"gce_instance\""},"displayName":"Test_two"}],"displayName":"test","combiner":"OR"}
```

I'm not able to make my function work because of the `duration` value. I've tried to pass as a string, an interger, a string with s and I always have an error:

`TypeError: Parameter to MergeFrom() must be instance of same class: expected google.protobuf.Duration got str.` or `TypeError: Parameter to MergeFrom() must be instance of same class: expected google.protobuf.Duration got int.`

How should I pass this value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: [MetricAbsence](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.alertPolicies#MetricAbsence)

It needs to be a string `"900s"` (probably).

Google's (increasingly?) exposing underlying Protobuf types in its APIs and these can be confusing to grok. In this case, the underlying type [Duration](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.Duration), is one of Google's so-called [Well-Known Types](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf). Ironically named because they're often not that well-known ;-)

Google's [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) is an excellent tool for this type of diagnosis. It is exhaustive and current:

- [Cloud Monitoring API v3](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/)
- [projects.alertPolicies.create](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.alertPolicies/create)
- [alertPolicies](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.alertPolicies#Condition)
- [Condition](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.alertPolicies#Condition)

##### Example

In this case, I start with a Python dictionary, `json.dumps` to convert it to a string and then `from_json` it to create a `monitoring_v3.AlertPolicy` that's needed by `create_alert_policy`

```py
import json
import os

from google.cloud import monitoring_v3


PROJECT = os.environ["PROJECT"]

client = monitoring_v3.AlertPolicyServiceClient()

name = "projects/{project}".format(project=PROJECT)

filter = "..."

j = {
    "displayName": "test",
    "conditions": [{
        "displayName": "test",
        "condition_absent": {
            "filter": filter,
            "duration": "900s",
        },
    }],
    "combiner": "OR"
}

policy = monitoring_v3.AlertPolicy.from_json(json.dumps(j))

resp = client.create_alert_policy(name=name,alert_policy=policy)

print(resp)
```

Then:

```sh
gcloud alpha monitoring policies list \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="value(displayName)"

test
```

Comment: Hi @DazWilkin I did try "900s" and I did try the APIs Explorer. There is no python in the API Explorer and It works with "900s" but not in my cloud function. I have the error `expected google.protobuf.Duration got str.`

Comment: Added an example

Comment: ok so I was missing the from_json method; thanks a lot.

Comment: This is a complete and utter mess. We're using Google Dataproc operators for Airflow, and they expect a dictionary. However, this method turns this into a `Message`, so we cannot trigger our cluster from Airflow now. ‍♂️

Comment: Found the solution. The method accepts either a dictionary or `ClusterConfig`. You can convert a `Message` to a `ClusterConfig` easily with the constructor